# Почему разные версии компилятора C++ по разному скомпилируют даный код? В чём конкретно разница?

Tags: c++, классы, vector, компилятор

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class ClassA{
public:
  ClassA(){cout << "+" << endl;}
};
int main(){
  vector<ClassA> vectorOfObjectsA;
  vectorOfObjectsA.resize(2);
  return 0;
}
```

результат работы в разных версиях компилятора:

```
sh-4.4$ g++ -std=c++17 -o main *.cpp
sh-4.4$ main
+
+
sh-4.4$ g++ -std=c++14 -o main *.cpp
sh-4.4$ main
+
+
sh-4.4$ g++ -std=c++11 -o main *.cpp
sh-4.4$ main
+
+
sh-4.4$ g++ -std=c++0x -o main *.cpp
sh-4.4$ main
+
+
sh-4.4$ g++ -std=c++03 -o main *.cpp
sh-4.4$ main
+
sh-4.4$ g++ -std=c++98 -o main *.cpp
sh-4.4$ main
+
sh-4.4$
```

Код запускался на сайте: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_cpp_compiler.php

Comment: потому что это разные компиляторы

Comment: А в чём конкретно разница? почему разные компиляторы по-разному реагируют на код?

Comment: По разному не реагируют, у них просто разные возможности. Читайте ответ от пользователья  VTT

Comment: Почему в старых версиях компилятор не вызывал конструктор класса при увеличении размера вектора?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в разных стандартах предусмотрены разные перегрузки для этой функции. До C++11 `resize` принимал на вход элемент для вставки в качестве опционального параметра и копировал его n раз:

```
void resize( size_type count, 
    T value = T() ); // один вызов конструктора по-умолчанию
```

Но начиная с C++ 11 будет вызываться другая перегрузка, создающая до n объектов  вызовом конструктора по-умолчанию:

```
void resize( size_type count );
```

Comment: то есть в старых версиях компиляторов при вызове функции `resize()` вторым элементом вектора становилась копия первого элемента, а в новых версиях для второго элемента просто вызывался конструктор по умолчанию?

Comment: Уместнее было бы процитировать спецификацию `resize`, которая поменялась совершенно аналогичным образом. Конструктор вектора в коде из вопроса используется другой.

Comment: соглашусь, цитаты или хотя бы точной ссылки на стандарт в ответе  очень не хватает...

Comment: @Taras Viyatyk,  в новых версиях  конструктор перемещения  скорее вызывается

Comment: @TarasViyatyk В старой версии сначала создавался объект - параметр функции, затем для первого и для второго элемента вызывался конструктор копирования.